# Какого специалиста мне нужно искать для решения моей задачи?

Tags: браузер, кроссплатформенность, спецификация

У нас есть определенный продукт и сейчас нам понадобилось создать кроссплатформенное приложение. Для решения этой задачи я собираюсь искать специалиста(студию, фрилансера), поэтому интересуюсь, кого и где лучше искать?

Вкратце, нам нужен **кроссплатформенный браузер**(на основе какого-то браузера или написанный с нуля), в котором должны быть реализованы:

1. Регистрация(+вход) аккаунта
2. Настройки аккаунта
3. В зависимости от аккаунта должны подтягиваться нужные нам настройки(user agent, cookie, proxy, …)
4. Привязка по железу(т.е. 1 аккаунт = 1 устройство)
5. Реализована возможность оплаты подписки на браузер

И в дополнение создана база данных клиентов(дата оплаты и т.д.) и их собственных настроек браузера. И при входе его данные бы подтягивались в браузер.

На чём это лучше всего написать(чтоб еще *какая никакая защита* была), какой нам нужен специалист, какими скиллами он должен обладать и где его лучше всего искать?

**Спасибо.**

Comment: Для этой задачи Вам подойдет ElectronJS - это движок для создания приложений, за основу взят браузер Chromium. Приложение можно собрать под любую десктопную ось. Так же можете посмотреть и в сторону Quasar.dev - фреймворк поддерживающий ElectronJS (десктопные приложения) и Cordova (мобильные приложения Android и iOS) и создание Web-приложений.

Comment: Спасибо  за ответ, @SnakeMS 
Насколько я понимаю по итоговой Электрон создает app.asap, который легко распаковать и украсть код. Читал что защититься от этого нельзя, только сделав код нечитабельным. Это так?
Именно поэтому начали смотреть в сторону того, чтоб делать бэк на питоне, джаве или гоу, но не смогли решить.

Если от этого можно защититься (хотя бы чтоб вор должен был обладать диким скиллом)  это бы нам помогло. Спасибо